# replacing multiple instances of html with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

HTML:

```
<div class="slide">
  <div class="left">
    <img src="img-lg.png" class="image1" />
  </div>
  <div class="thumbs">
    <img src="img-sm.png" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="slide">         
  <div class="left">
    <img src="anotherimg-lg.png" class="image1" />
  </div>
  <div class="thumbs">
    <img src="anotherimg-sm.png" />
  </div>    
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
var originalContent = $('.left').html();
$("div.thumbs img").hover(function(){
  var largesrc = $(this).attr("src").replace("sm","lg");
  $(".left").html('<img src="' + largesrc 
    + '" width="560" height="377" class="largeimage" />');
}, function() {
  $(".left").html(originalContent);
});
```

I am replacing the large image with the smaller one on hover and then reverting back to the original. This works fine, but I can't figure out how to get it to work with multiple instances.

In the second slide set, the left image gets replaced by the original first left image and not the second.

Comment: your $(.left') is missing a quote, i guess its a typo

Comment: Yes, it was. Thanks for catching that!

Comment: I guess you need to get html of parent of left originalContent = $('div.left').parent().html(); and then replace it $('div.left').parent().html(originalContent);

Comment: Can you please share a screen shot to make clear what you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("div.thumbs img").hover(function(){
  var $this = $(this);

  // find the containing .slide, then find .left within that
  var left = $this.closest('.slide').find('.left');

  // store the original content as "data" on `left`, so
  // we can get it easily in the future
  left.data('originalContent', left.html());

  var largesrc = $this.attr("src").replace("sm","lg");
  left.html('<img src="' + largesrc 
    + '" width="560" height="377" class="largeimage" />');
}, function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var left = $this.closest('.slide').find('.left');

  // fetch the "data" we stored earlier, and restore it
  left.html(left.data('originalContent'));
});
```

A live example is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/coltrane/4VLEr/).

Comment: It's so close, thank you! But, I'm still at the same spot because the second slide reverts back to the original image of the first slide and I need it to show the original image of the second slide instead.

Comment: sorry, there was an error: `left.data('originalContent', $('.left').html()` *should* have been `left.data('originalContent', left.html())`.  I've corrected my example above.

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
$("div.thumbs img").hover(function(){
        $(this).closest('.slide').find('.left img').attr({
            src: this.src.replace("sm","lg"),
            width: 560,
            height: 377,
            'class': 'largeimage'
        });
}, 
function() {
        var img = $(this).closest('.slide').find('.left img');
        img.attr({src: img[0].src.replace("lg","sm")})
        .removeAttr('width height class');
});
```

Here you swap the `src` property of the image element, without modifying the dom structure.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/H43Xa/4/)

Comment: This is a lot cleaner than I had, thank you! The only problem is that I need to replace the image in the left div for each slide and then revert back.

Comment: I think this will help the images load faster. Thank you!